# Is it OK to upvote unhelpful posts made by new users?

Tags: discussion, new-users, upvotes

I am a new user and I cannot tell you how bad I wanted to comment on posts. When I finally unlocked the privilege to vote and comment I was so happy. I want to upvote posts for new users so that they can unlock the basic functions of the app.

Is it considered unethical or does it mess up the algorithm to upvote new user posts
even if the posts aren't exactly helpful?

Comment: Of course it's ok to upvote posts made by new users... Why wouldn't it be? how new a user is or how much rep they have etc isn't relevant to voting. Are you asking whether or not it's ok to *indiscriminately* vote on posts by new users regardless of the post value/usefulness? because that distinction is important.

Comment: If you yourself "am a new user" and "finally unlocked the privilege to vote and comment" that got you "happy" which most likely was the result of some one else upvoting your posts, doesn't it answer the question of if it was ok or not?

Comment: No, voting based on the user and not the content they are posting is a form of voting fraud.

Comment: Lol I feel so stupid. What I was trying to ask was if I can upvote just for the sake of helping them even if the posts aren't helpful to me.

Comment: "I want to upvote posts for new users so that they can unlock the basic functions of the app." - If you need to be told that voting on a user's contribution because they are new to the community isn't a reason to upvote their contribution, then you need to read the help center and the guidelines surrounding voting in general.  "What I was trying to ask was if I can upvote just for the sake of helping them even if the posts aren't helpful to me." - No;  You are not allowed to do this.

Comment: "What I was trying to ask was if I can upvote just for the sake of helping them even if the posts aren't helpful to me." you _can_ vote this way, but it's not the intent of voting and potentially abusive if it's a pattern of targeting a specific user. The intent of voting is to communicate which answers are valuable the community and which aren't. It should have nothing to do with the user. People misunderstand Stack Overflow, possibly because they haven't used it themselves to _find information_. It's about curating a repository of knowledge that people can use to find answers.

Comment: Meta site score voting includes expressing agreement/approval. [Help]

Comment: You probably have 100% the wrong idea of what Stack Overflow is if you have this level of enthusiasm and excitement. Do more reading, please. This same meta site is also the source of all your information. I would start by skimming through the top rated meta posts, pretty much all meta posts have links to other fascinating meta posts so you'll be busy for days. Stack Overflow is not an easy site to be a good citizen on.

Comment: Not sure if edits were completely fair for this question. @AlphaReuel, what do you mean by "aren't helpful to me" exactly? If you see objectively good answer, even if it is not related you or your situation in any way - upvote it. But, as mentioned before, please avoid opening multiple posts of the same user and upvoting them all, just for the sake of "helping". Also, please be aware of influx of GPT generated answers, that look good, but factually incorrect.

Comment: It's not OK to upvote unhelpful posts from _anyone_.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you are asking the wrong question. According to the [SO help page on voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote):

> **Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful**, while
> voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong
> information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate
> information. The more that people vote on a post, the more certain
> future visitors can be of the quality of information contained within
> that post – not to mention that **upvotes are a great way to thank the
> author of a good post for the time and effort put into writing it!**

It has nothing to do with being a new user.

Answer (score 4):

In short, no.

> I want to upvote posts for new users so that they can unlock the basic functions of the app.

If we thought this was a good idea, the restrictions wouldn't be there in the first place.

Upvoting to "game the system" or "be nice" to other users defeats the purpose of that system. People are expected to have a couple well-received questions and/or answers before they can participate fully.

Among other things, it means that the anti-spam systems overwhelmingly only have to worry about questions and answers. Spam in comments requires moderator action and can't be handled by the community, and is harder to detect (no, spammers *don't* always want you to notice that there is an ad; a lot of it is about tricking search engines). But fortunately for us, barely any spammers will want to go to the trouble of reaching a 50 reputation score. Similarly, the system allows curators with extensive experience to mark some questions as "protected", which prevents spammers from adding answers to the most-viewed parts of the site and minimizes the impact of new users who don't understand that the answer section is *only for posting answers*. Similarly for other privileges - you get the idea.